# How to implement a custom formatter in a Quarkus app that uses org.jboss.logging.Logger with quarkus-logging-json extension

Tags: quarkus

I am using *quarkus-logging-json* extension to format logs into a json format in my *Quarkus* project.

When an exception is thrown, the log contains a property key with name *exception* and a nested json as its value. I want to change the value field to a delimited string.

There is an application config property `quarkus.log.console.json.exception-output-type=formatted` provided, which converts the exception value from a json to a delimited string, however it does so by replacing the property name with *stackTrace*

Is there a way to override the logging formatter with a custom formatter for more flexibility?